Vincular datos entre widgets de Tradingview
No se si alguien tiene experiencia con los widgets de tradingview.
Actualmente tengo un proyecto que me demanda incluir varios de estos widgets en una plataforma web.
Los widgets funcionan correctamente, el problema en el que me encuentro ahora es que los widgets no se vinculan entre si, es decir, si tengo el widget de una gráfica y tengo otro widget con información sobre algún mercado, al cambiar de mercado en la gráfica, el widget que tiene la información no se actualiza.
No pude encontrar ninguna información al respecto en la documentación de Tradingview, asi que agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar!
Como podrán ver, estuve buscando alguna solución en chatgp pero todavía sigo sin alguna solución.
Para que entiendan mejor mi problema les dejo esta foto en la que pueden ver 2 widgets distintos, uno de información arriba y una grafica abajo.
Quiero que cuando cambie el mercado en la gráfica de abajo, se actualize la información de arriba.

Les dejo mi código abajo. Un abrazo!
HTML:
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
          <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js" async>
              {
                "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                  "width": 550,
                    "locale": "es",
                      "colorTheme": "dark",
                        "isTransparent": true
              }
            </script>
        </div>

      <div class="tradingview-widget-container" id="tradingview_advanced_chart" style="height:100%;width:100%">
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget" style="height:calc(100% - 32px);width:100%"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-advanced-chart.js" async>
            {
              "autosize": true,
                "height": "610",
                  "interval": "5",
                    "timezone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
                      "style": "1",
                        "locale": "en",
                          "backgroundColor": "#050505",
                            "hide_side_toolbar": false,
                              "gridColor": "#050505",

                                "allow_symbol_change": true,
                                  "watchlist": [
                                    "FX:GBPUSD",
                                    "FX:USDJPY",
                                    "FX:AUDUSD",
                                    "FX:USDCAD",
                                    "FX:GBPJPY",
                                    "FX:USDCHF",
                                    "FX:GBPAUD",
                                    "FX:EURJPY"
                                  ],
                                    "theme": "dark",
                                      "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                                        "calendar": false,
                                          "studies": [
                                            "STD;VWAP"
                                          ],
                                            "support_host": "https://www.tradingview.com"
            }
          </script>
          

      </div>

JS:
<script>
// Función que actualiza el símbolo en el gráfico avanzado
function updateAdvancedChart(symbol) {
  const chartIframe = document.querySelector('#tradingview_advanced_chart iframe');
  if (chartIframe) {
    chartIframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
      event: 'set_symbol',
      symbol: symbol
    }, '*');
  }
}

// Espera a que el widget del screener cargue completamente
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  if (event.origin !== 'https://screener.tradingview.com') return;

  // Escucha los clicks en el screener
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'click') {
    const clickedSymbol = event.data.symbol;
    updateAdvancedChart(clickedSymbol);
  }
}, false);


Quizás deberias leerte esto para cambiar el símbolo dinámicamente: https://www.tradingview.com/widget-docs/tutorials/build-page/dynamic-symbols/#complete-code

Ya lo probé. Pero por algún motivo cuando cambio el símbolo en la gráfica los demas widgets no se cambian.

Lo que necesito básicamente es que cuando cambio de símbolo en la gráfica, todos los demás widgets se cambien al mismo símbolo sin necesidad de recargar la página, ¿es esto posible?

Deberia poder serlo, pero no creo que con el método que intentas lo consigas, primero porque no estas analizando bien el event, que es un JSON y debes parsearlo para llegar a sus propiedades, pero aunque lo hagas, luego el postmessage() tampoco te hace caso (ya lo he probado antes). Así que me inclino a que lo hagas reescribiendo el div del widget creando un nuevo widget con el simbolo adecuado en lugar de intentar modificar el iframe del widget actual pues no parece que haga ni caso y no ha encontrado más bien nada de documentación al respecto.
